# Get exact values of width and height of cv2.minAreaRect()

Tags: python, image, opencv, object

I am using a script to measure the size of objects using OpenCV. For my `pixel_to_mm_ratio` I use an `Aruco` Marker. This is done with exact values.

To draw boxes around the other objects I first find contours and then draw rectangles around them with `cv.minAreaRect()`. My problem is that width (w) and height (h) are not given as exact numbers (float) but are already rounded (integer):

```
rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)
(x, y), (w, h), angle = rect
```

Through the rounding of these numbers (w and h) from rectangles around contours i later get an inaccuracy when calculating the width and height in mm.

```
object_width = w / pixel_mm_ratio
object_height = h / pixel_mm_ratio
```

Is there a way to get the exact values from `cv2.minAreaRect()`? Or an other way to grab these values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem starts earlier: the contours are based on discrete pixels and so have only coordinates in integers.

Comment: Understandable... is there a way to measure width and height in a different way? The inaccuracy isnt big, but its there...